# Compare and mark from two sheets in excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a sheet [image]
which i have to compare it with my another sheets data
here i want to compare Column A from first sheet two Row 1 in second Sheet and mark the diffenece in both and highlight it.
[image]

Comment: How you will differentiate? What is logic? What is data in sheet2? It just showing `####` expand column and then take screenshot.

Comment: Conditional Formatting with a custom formula that looks like IsError(Match(A7, Sheet2!$B:$B,0))